# SQLite - recursive query to obtain value based on parent

Tags: sqlite, recursive-query

I have an SQLite table that has a structure similar to the following:

| ID | TYPE | PARENT_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | A | 1050 |
| 1001 | B | 1067 |
| 1002 |  | 1000 |
| 1003 | C | 1100 |
| 1004 | B | 1378 |
| 1005 |  | 1002 |
| 1006 |  |  |

I need to create an SQL query that returns all records with the TYPE column populated where it is empty using the PARENT_ID, ignoring those that do not have a PARENT_ID. The result should be the following:

| ID | TYPE | PARENT_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | A | 1050 |
| 1001 | B | 1067 |
| 1002 | A | 1000 |
| 1003 | C | 1100 |
| 1004 | B | 1378 |
| 1005 | A | 1002 |
| 1006 |  |  |

You will note that for ID 1005, the SQL query will need to recursively query using the PARENT_ID to ultimately retrieve a TYPE value of A from the record with ID of 1000.

I assume the recursive functions in SQL will help with this requirement, but as I have not used recursive SQL before, I need some help building the SQL query.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using the recursive CTE.

The recursive CTE will not return any records without parent_id so we can simply add them using `union all`

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT id, type, parent_id
  FROM mytable 
  WHERE type is not null
  UNION ALL
  SELECT l.id, c.type, l.parent_id
  FROM mytable l 
  INNER JOIN cte c
  ON l.parent_id = c.id
)
SELECT *
from cte
union all
select *
from mytable 
where parent_id is null
order by id
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/7HprfBpp)